# Negative Currency Display

Tags: php, money-format

I have this code

```
echo money_format('£%i', $PL);
```

But for negative output the display is

> £-1.00

I want

> -£1.00

How can I get the - sign before the pound sign?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_GB');
echo money_format('%+n', -123.45); // -£123.45
```

If you can not see the symbol correctly, try using:

```
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_GB.UTF-8');
echo money_format('%+n', -123.45);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php